# How do I implement a DependencyProperty in an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a usercontrol (DeckList) which consists of an ItemsControl that simply displays 3 Labels side by side in a grid.

```
<ItemsControl x:Class="OpponentDeck.DeckList"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OpponentDeck"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

  <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
      <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--<Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="{Binding Card.Background}" Height="34" Width="217" />-->
        <Label x:Name="lblCost" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Card.Cost}" Foreground="LimeGreen" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="Black" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Tekton Pro" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblCard" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Card.Name}" Foreground="{Binding TextColor, ElementName=lblCard}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="Black" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Tekton Pro" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblQty" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Qty}" Foreground="LimeGreen" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="Black" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Tekton Pro" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

That usercontrol (DeckList) is used in another UserControl (UI) which is added to the main window.  This usercontrol consists of a stackpanel with 2 DeckLists side by side.  When defining the UI.xaml, I would like to specify the color of the labels by setting a property.  I have this markup to do that

```
    <controls1:DeckList TextColor="LimeGreen"  x:Name="playableCards" Width="150"></controls1:DeckList>
```

Codebehind for the DeckList has a DependencyProperty and a Property Get/Set

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(DeckList), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.HotPink)));
```

```
        public System.Windows.Media.Brush TextColor {
            get { return (System.Windows.Media.Brush)GetValue(TextColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextColorProperty, value); }
        }
```

I am pretty sure the problem has something to do with my binding, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to get it working.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
<Label x:Name="lblCard" Foreground="{Binding TextColor, ElementName=lblCard}" .../>
```

which can't work because Label has no `TextColor` property.

In order to use the `TextColor` property of the DeckList control, use

```
Foreground="{Binding TextColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
```